# how to connect Mesos to existing dse cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, datastax, mesos

I have a dse cluster base on docker. Now I want to use Mesos to manage my dse cluster for running spark job. So I installed Mesos master, Mesos slave docker container. What should I do next to connect dse to mesos?

Comment: Can you describe (draw) your setup? If I understand you correctly you have standalone DSE cluster and will query it with Spark running on Mesos?

Comment: You want to use your own spark managed by mesos?